# How to access a variable in a function from inside a jsp tag

Tags: javascript, eclipse, string, jsp, var

I have the following function:

```
 <script>
  function assign()
  {
  var val = "";
  val = document.form1.text1.value;
  alert(val); 
  }
```

I want to access the variable val's value inside jsp tag so that i can pass it to the googlePlus method as a String. I tried making var val as a global variable, but it doesnt work. How can I access the variable val inside the following code?

```
<%
String output = "";
if ( Boolean.valueOf(request.getParameter("submitted")) == true ) {
    Scraping h = new Scraping();
    output  = h.googlePlus();
}
%>
```

Comment: You can't access the variable. Your JSP/Java code runs on the web server and your JavaScript runs in the browser - neither can access the other one's variables. You can submit the form that contains the field that the value came from and access it as a request parameter. Or make an Ajax request from your JS, where again the Java would receive the value as a request parameter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the value of the variable using a assignment operator to some hidden JSP field and then use it in the JS using document.getElementById(). the code would be somewhat like:
`<input type="hidden" value="<%=output%>">`
Or alternatively if your js is residing inside the JSP only
var s = "<%=output%>"; should work!
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can't access javascript variables via JSP Java Code.

Your JSP & Java codes are compiled at server side.

And your javascript runs in a browser.

So send the 'val' variable to your servlet by form submit, ajax or whatever.